# C++ converting PHP code adding numbers to string

Tags: php, c++

I'm trying to convert PHP code to C++.

```
$this->Key + 1 + log2p (floor($TimePlot/$this->kY)*M_PI-2*20
```

In PHP Key is string in C++ key2 is char*, timeplot is time_t and val is int.

```
key2 + 1 + log2(floor((double)timeplot/this->val*M_PI-2*20))
```

and the error is:
**error C2111: '+' : pointer addition requires integral operand**

I don't know what to do to make it working. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to cast your values. You can't just use "+" operator in C++.

Comment: But what is the problem here? What value should I cast?

Comment: In C++, you start by using [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) instead of raw character pointers. Then you can use e.g. [`std::to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) to converts numbers to a string and append it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your $this->key is string, and you want to end up with a string in C++ also, then you need to do something like this:

```
char bf[1024];
sprintf (bf, "%f", 1.0 + log2(floor((double)timeplot/this->val*M_PI-2*20)) );
std::string k = key2;
k += bf;
```

assuming everything else in your expression resolve to numeric values that can participate in numeric calculations. I used a buffer length of 1024 bytes here, you can adjust it accordingly.